# Localhost doesn't see my file; The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, localhost, port

I want to view my file in the browser, but I can’t do it with any localhost port.

I've tried `localhost:8080/test.php`, `localhost:8080/14l/test.php` and other ports.

That's how it looks:
[image: Not Found]

It just doesn't see any of my files.

Comment: Your question is like asking a mechanic why your car does not start without any other information...